# Javascript Promises in a loop behaves differently during jest test

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this function which has array map and a three level nested promise. 
Index.js

```
const promiseA=require('./promiseA')


console.log(' Starting ')
//setInterval(()=>console.log('executed'), 5000)

const sample=async ()=>{
    const newArray=[1,2,3,4,5]
    let result =undefined

    await Promise.all(newArray.map(async()=>{
        result = await promiseA();
        console.log('after calling A')
    }))
    console.log(`final result ${result}`)

    return result;
}
sample();
module.exports=sample
```

PromiseA

```
const promiseB=require('./promiseB')

const promiseA=async()=>{
    return Promise.resolve(await promiseB())
}

module.exports=promiseA
```

Promise B

```
const promiseC=require('./promiseC')


const promiseB=async()=>{
    return Promise.resolve(await promiseC())
}

module.exports=promiseB
```

Promise C

```
const promiseC=async()=>{
    return Promise.resolve([1,2,3])
}

module.exports=promiseC
```

When I did npm start I get the following output

```
 Starting 
after calling A
after calling A
after calling A
after calling A
after calling A
final result 1,2,3
```

The output is the same as the expected one.

Coming to jest.

index.test.js

```
const sample=require('../src/index')

describe('all tests', ()=>{

    it('should', async()=>{
        const result = await sample()
        expect(result).toBeDefined();
    })
})
```

when i did npm test, i get the following output

```
console.log
     Starting

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.js:7:9)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    final result 1,2,3

      at sample (src/index.js:33:13)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    after calling A

      at Promise.all.newArray.map (src/index.js:19:17)

  console.log
    final result 1,2,3

      at sample (src/index.js:33:13)
```

This is something I dont understand. The output is getting printed twice. Can someone please help. I have been stuck in a similar problem for the past 2 days.

Comment: Well, for some reason you are calling `sample();` before exporting it from *index.js*. When you require the module, that code runs. (As well as the `console.log(' Starting ')`). Then in the test, you're calling it again.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. I was under the impression that I was calling the function directly from the test class. Didn't know the require statement will run the code.

Comment: No, it needs to run the code that defines the function (and, in your case, also runs it). You probably should separate this into two files, an *index.js* where you declare it and a *main.js* where you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.js

```js
const promiseA=require('./promiseA')


console.log(' Starting ')
//setInterval(()=>console.log('executed'), 5000)

const sample=async ()=>{
    const newArray=[1,2,3,4,5]
    let result =undefined

    await Promise.all(newArray.map(async()=>{
        result = await promiseA();
        console.log('after calling A')
    }))
    console.log(`final result ${result}`)

    return result;
}
sample(); // <- you are calling it here
module.exports=sample
```

index.test.js

```js
const sample=require('../src/index')

describe('all tests', ()=>{

    it('should', async()=>{
        const result = await sample() // <- you are calling it here
        expect(result).toBeDefined();
    })
})
```

you are calling `sample` two times, once in `index.js` and once in `index.test.js`

Comment: You are right. I was under the impression that test file just calls sample function directly.